# Spring webflow can't access mvc beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to use some @Service annotated classes (yes, using the mvc:annotation-driven) within the following Web flow :

#### *manage-flow.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" start-state="start" >



<view-state id="start" view="Userview.jsp" >

<on-render>

    <set name="flowScope.users"
        value="UserService.getUsers()">
    </set>
</on-render>
</view-state>
<bean-import resource="Manage-Beans.xml"/>
</flow>
```

#### *Manage-Beans.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean class="com.dproductions.test.Service.SiteService" id="SiteService" />
<bean class="com.dproductions.test.Service.CustomerService" id="CustomerService" />
<bean class="com.dproductions.test.Service.UserService" id="UserService" />

 </beans>
```

When attempting to reach the flow I get the following stacktrace : http: //pastebin.com/QmCXe45Y

Which comes down to the Webflow not being able to access the specified package(s).
But it doesn't give a 'ClassNotFoundException' , which is sort of puzzling to me.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Besides, my servlet-context is found here : [Servlet-context](http://pastebin.com/2HHvDRUK)

I've been fighting this for over a week now.

*Edit*

I want to be able to use my beans the way they are used at [This Example](http://www.javabeat.net/2010/10/introduction-to-spring-web-flow-swf/2/) , at the action states, the beans being picked up/managed directly by Spring MVC .
Do the beans have to be declared (and serializable?) in the applicationcontext ? Using xml-notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the

```
<set>
```

towards an

```
<evaluate expression>
```

and have the beans defined in the file Manage-Beans.xml , it works.

But that way I have to define the same bean twice, as it is once picked up by the pkg-search annotation, and then in the web-flow it is again. 
I'd like to have the beans which are already made.

Spring web flow DOES re-create/instantiate the bean again. You can reference properties, autowire them with beans in the web-flow beans import file, but it's like a new context, unaware of existing beans. 
(Using events goes to both flow and normal-context files.)

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: unnamed; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/flows/manage/Userview.jsp]
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:191)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
>     org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)

Check the view file location.

Comment: but in your application context its the ViewResolver  is configured as <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />

Comment: Yes, which is correct. For certainty I've put the view in the folder containing the view, but the view is in the views folder as well. That should make this a certainty of a correct location as far as I'm aware. When removing the     <on-render>
 
  <set name="flowScope.users"
   value="UserService.getUsers()">
  </set>
 </on-render>    it loaded perfectly fine, except for having no data of course. So the location is not the problem, it is accessing the beans defined in Spring MVC (annotation-based)